# Select MAX value that does not count the row I'm at

Tags: postgresql

I'm building a query that returns a sale number and a flag that tells me if before that sale, any onther sales for that person have been at least 33% paid

The table I'm working has the sale number (id_trx), the persons number (cpf) and the % paid (paidp)

Heres the max I'm trying, it works for most cases, but if the sale I'm looking has a bigger % then the previously, the max will show this %, but I need to analyse the previous ones

```
select
    id_trx,
    cpf,
    paidp,
    max(paidp) over (partition by cpf order by id_trx asc)
from c
```

Any suggestions to how make this max without considering the value of the row I'm at?

Comment: Use `rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding`

Comment: @MikeOrganeq: Post as answer?